# Complexity Time O(n) or O(n(n+1)/2)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

What the complexity of algorithm that loops on n items (like array) then on (n-1) then (n-2)and so on Like:

```
Loop(int[] array) {
  for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++) {
     //do some thing

  }
}
Main() {
   Loop({1, 2, 3, 4}); 
   Loop({1, 2, 3}); 
   Loop({1, 2}); 
   Loop({1}); 
//What the complexity of this code.
}
```

What is the complexity of the previous program?

Comment: `O(n(n+1)/2) = O(n^2)`

Comment: Big-O notation ignores constants and drops lower order terms, so it would be O(n**2)

Comment: That also really depends on what the `n` is in your case - currently one could argue that your code runs in `O(1)`! You should probably program the code in `Main` as a function that takes an array of length `n` and loops over `Loop` - then it's clear that it is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that what you do in the loop is `O(1)`, The complexity of this is `O(n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1) = O(n(n+1)/2) = O(0.5n^2 + 0.5n) = O(n^2)`

- The first `=` is due to arithmetic series sum.
- The second `=` is due to opening the multiplication.
- The third `=` is due to the fact that given a polynomial inside an `O()` you can simply replace it with `x^highest_power`

Comment: Yes, we ignore constants

Answer (score 5):

**Formula**:

```
               n*(n+1)
n + ... + 1 = ─────────
                  2
```

**Proof**:

```
n + ... + 1 = S

2*(n + ... + 1) = 2*S

n + n-1 + ... + 2   + 1 + 
1 + 2   + ... + n-1 + n = 2*S

n+1 + (n-1)+2 + ... + 2+(n-1) + 1+n = 2*S

n+1 + n+1 + ... + n+1 = 2*S

n*(n+1) = 2*S 

S = n*(n+1)/2 = (n*n+n)/2
```

But:

```
 n*n     n*n + n          n*n + n*n
───── < ───────── = S < ──────────── = n*n
  2         2                 2
```

1. Our sum is lower than (or equal to for n=1) `n*n` (for every `n`, but it's enough to be true for every `n > n0`). The assumption above is based on the fact that n >= 1 => n*n >= n.
2. `n*n` is in **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

From (1) and (2) => our sum is in **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

If we use the lower limit (`n*n/2`), we can also say that it is in **Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)** and then in **Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

---

**Formal definition**

You can also prove it based on the **formal definition**, but I found the explanation above more intuitive.

> f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and n0, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n0. The values of c and n0 must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.

```
f(n) = (n*n+n)/2
g(n) = n*n
```

Just choose `n0 = 1` and `c = 2`, and you get:

```
0 ≤ (n*n+n)/2 ≤ 2*n*n
0 ≤ n*n+n ≤ 4*n*n
0 ≤ n ≤ 3*n*n
```

which is obviously true for every `n ≥ n0=1`.

In general, if you have problems when you choose the constants, use bigger values. E.g.: `n0=10`, `c=100`. Sometimes it will be more obvious.